# JSON Results To A Drop down List

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu

Hi I am Working On a Web Form..
I Have A combo Box for holding all The Units.
I Have Taken All The units from the Database Using JSON,now i need to Bind All these Units To the drop down List
How can I Do this...?

```
    function getUnitFamily(pack_detl_ID,select) {
        //***********************************//
        PageMethods.getUnitFamily(pack_detl_ID,
                                function(result) {
                                    if (result != null) {
                                        custinfo = eval(result);
                                        if (custinfo != null) {


                                            $('#<%=drpUnit.ClientID%> option').remove();
                                            var objSub = document.getElementById('<%=drpUnit.ClientID%>');
                                            $.each(custinfo, function(i, item) {

                             listOpt = document.createElement("option");
                                                listOpt.value = item[0];
                                                listOpt.text = item[1];
                                                objSub.add(listOpt);
                                            });

                                            alert(select);
                    document.getElementById('<%= drpUnit.ClientID %>').value = select;


                                        }
                                    }
                                }, pageMethodError);
```

With An example can any one  explain

Comment: This is more of a question for Google.

Answer (score 0):

A combobox sounds like you are using an ASP.NET control. Of course, you can bind your items to that control in the code behind. If you are doing some AJAX stuff and have a dropdown ( element>) in your page which you want to populate at client side, you might want to take a look at what [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) has to offer. For example use the [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) api to retrieve your data and push that data into your dropdown like so:

```
var options = $("#options"); 
$.each(result, function() { 
    options.append($("<option />").val("sometext").text("sometext")); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used a plugin when working with dropdowns.

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select

Request the JSON data:

```
//Get the JSON Data
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
   PopulateDropDownFromJson(json, "#element");
});
```

and then just pass the JSON into a function that uses the plugin above

```
function PopulateDropDownFromJson(json, element){
   $.each(json, function() {
   $(element).addOption(this[valueText], this[displayText], false);
});

}
```